# Cloud Recording issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, agora.io

I am trying agora cloud Recording API and trying to record into AWS S3 bucket. The calls appear to go through fine. While doing stop record, I get success message. I have reproduced part of it here:
       {
        insertId:  "5d66423d00012ad9d6d02f2b"
        labels: {
           clone_id:
    "00c61b117c803f45c35dbd46759dc85f8607177c3234b870987ba6be86fec0380c162a"
         }
        lotextPayload:  "Stop cloud recording success. FileList : 
        01ce51a4a640ecrrrrhxabd9e9d823f08_tdeaon_20197121758.m3u8, uploading 
        status: backuped"
        timestamp:  "2019-08-28T08:58:37.076505Z"
      }

It shows the status 'backuped'. As per agora documentation, it uploaded the files into agora cloud. Then within 5 minutes it is supposed to upload into my AWS S3 bucket. 
I am not seeing this file in my AWS bucket. I have tested the bucket secret key. the same key works fine for other application. Also I have verified CORS settings.

Please suggest how I could debug further.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are inputing your S3 credentials correctly within the `storageConfig` settings

```
"storageConfig":{
  "vendor":{{StorageVendor}},
  "region":{{StorageRegion}},
  "bucket":"{{Bucket}}",
  "accessKey":"{{AccessKey}}",
  "secretKey":"{{SecretKey}}"
}
```

Agora offers a Postman collection to make testing easier: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest

Answer (score 0):

I had faced issue due to wrong uid.

1. Recording uid needs to be a random id which will be used for 'joining by the recording client which 'resides' on cloud. I had passed my main client's id.

Other two reasons I had faced:

2. S3 credentials
3. S3 CORS settings : Go to AWS S3 permissions and set the allowed CORS headers.

EDIT:
It could be something like this on S3 side ..

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-meta-custom-header",
            "x-amz-storage-class"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 5000
    }
]
```

Comment: can you please share the CORS setting, i have tried it but still no luck.Thanks

Comment: It could be something like this on S3 side .. [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-meta-custom-header",
            "x-amz-storage-class"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 5000
    }
]